# how to fetch data in block Magento2?

Tags: php-5.4, magento2.2

In Table1:

```
Id  Category-Name  Status
1    Account       Enable
2    Shipping      Disable
3    Payment       Enable
```

In Table2:

```
Id  Category-Name  Question  Answer  Status  Position
1   1              Acc       Data     Enable  1
2   3              Del       Quw      Enable  2
3   1              Ship      Wae      Disable  3
4   1              Pay       Que      Disable   4
```

how to get categoryName in table1 using Category_name in table2?

Comment: You need to do a joint SQL, you have a repository for your tables?

Comment: expected output:Account->acc,Shipping->ship,Payment->Del

Comment: your comment is not clear

Comment: i want to display what are the question under category name Accout?

Comment: Is it clear?wt can  i do

Comment: Its cleat but tell me if you have a collection or a repository for your models?

Comment: collection......